# How to ensure FTP file upload on windows shutdown event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a windows Desktop Server-Client application where client sends messages to server application via Signal-R and perform some FTP operation periodically. Can anyone suggest a way to detect windows shutdown trigger and wait until uploading a file to FTP server.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use [`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) to block the ShoutDown proc, providing a reason for the delay as a message to the User. Sample (working) code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691726/7444103)

Comment: Hi Jimi, Thanks for reply. Surely I will try your sample.